# Return the most similar document compared to a query document by using Cosine similarity in python

Tags: python, vector, vocabulary, tf-idf, cosine-similarity

I have a set of files and a query doc.My purpose is to return the most similar documents by comparing with query doc for each of the document.To use cosine similarity first i have to map the document strings to vectors.Also i have already created a tf-idf function that calculate for each of the document.

To get the index of the strings i have a function like that ;

```
def getvectorKeywordIndex(self, documentList):
    """ create the keyword associated to the position of the elements within the    document vectors """
    #Mapped documents into a single word string
    vocabularyString = " ".join(documentList)
    vocabularylist= vocabularyString.split(' ')
    vocabularylist= list(set(vocabularylist))
    print 'vocabularylist',vocabularylist
    vectorIndex={}
    offset=0
    #Associate a position with the keywords which maps to the dimension on the vector used to represent this word
    for word in vocabularylist:
        vectorIndex[word]=offset
        offset+=1
  print vectorIndex
  return vectorIndex,vocabularylist  #(keyword:position),vocabularylist
```

and for cosine similarity my function is that;

```
 def cosine_distance(self,index, queryDoc):

    vector1= self.makeVector(index)
    vector2= self.makeVector(queryDoc)

    return numpy.dot(vector1, vector2) / (math.sqrt(numpy.dot(vector1, vector1)) * math.sqrt(numpy.dot(vector2, vector2)))
```

TF-IDF is ;

```
def tfidf(self, term, key):

    return (self.tf(term,key) * self.idf(term))
```

My problem is that how can i create the makevector by using the index and vocabulary list and also tf-idf inside of this function.
Any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `vectorIndex` to `makeVector` as well and use it to look up the indices for terms in documents and queries. Ignore terms that do not appear in `vectorIndex`.

Mind you, when dealing with documents you should really be using [`scipy.sparse`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) matrices instead of Numpy arrays, or you'll quickly run out of memory.

(Alternatively, consider using the [`Vectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.Vectorizer.html) in scikit-learn which handles all of this for you, uses `scipy.sparse` matrices and computes tf-idf values. Disclaimer: I wrote parts of that class.)